# Bootstrap text jumping issue

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I've seen examples online of bootstrap forms or fields with validations under inputs (ie: please enter username). And upon validation success the message is hidden, it appears that the text/elements below the focused input *jump* or shift upwards.
Just curious if there's something built into bootstrap that will help keep the elements in alignment, minus the shifting upwards when the validation is hidden.

Examples I've seen the issue with are both with

Here's an example from the bootstrap site itself. Submit the form and you'll see everything else under it shifting upwards when the validations appear/hide.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/validation/#custom-styles

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built in to bootstrap to control this - you are adding a new element to the page so it will cause layout changes.

On solution that you could do manually might be to add the text with `position: absolute` or other positioning that will position the text above the rest of the document flow. You would have to carefully manage your spacing though so that there is space for the text below the input.